# The age of a man before 20 years was five times of his son.what is the present age of his father , if after 16 years the are of son becomes 41 years?

Tags: problem-solving

The age of a man before 20 years was five times of his son.what is the present age of his father , if after 16 years the are of son becomes 41 years ?

Answer (score 2):

20 years before, the son's age was $41-16-20=5$.

The man's age 20 years ago was $5\times 5=25$.

The man's present age is $25+20=45$.